# Segue / uncaught exception error

Tags: ios, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to create an app with two basic screens, main and set-up. I transition from main to set-up using navigation controllers and segues, I rewind the segue to go from the set-up (screen 2) back to the main. all this works great!

I want to add a table with the help topics listed in the cells and i cannot get the help button to select the correct segue. I keep getting an uncaught exception error because the program is trying to perform he prepare to segue actions and send data back to the main screen. I am quite confused as to how to fix this problem. I used the navigation controllers and segues in lieu of just buttons etc to be more efficient and it seems to be more trouble!

```
#import "SignalViewController.h"
#import "SetUpViewController.h"

@interface SignalViewController ()

@end

@implementation SignalViewController

-(IBAction)unwindToSignalView:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{

    float minSlider = sensorMin;    //Get Slider range values
    float maxSlider = sensorMax;
    sensorValueSlider.minimumValue = minSlider;         //Set Slider Range
    sensorValueSlider.maximumValue = maxSlider;


    NSString* sensorMinD = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%.1f",sensorMin];//save default values next 9 lines
    NSString* sensorMaxD = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%.1f",sensorMax];
    NSString* signalMinD = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%.1f",signalMin];
    NSString* signalMaxD = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%.1f",signalMax];

    [labelY1 setText:sensorMinD];//set labels to match settings page next 3 lines
    [labelY3 setText:sensorMaxD];
    [labelX1 setText:signalMinD];
    [labelX3 setText:signalMaxD];

    //NSLog(@"signalMin: %f ", signalMin);
    //NSLog(@"signalMax: %f ", signalMax);
    //NSLog(@"sensorMin: %f ", sensorMin);
    //NSLog(@"sensroMax: %f ", sensorMax);

}


#import "SignalViewController.h"
#import "SetUpViewController.h"

@interface SetUpViewController ()


@end

@implementation SetUpViewController

@synthesize sensorMinY1;
@synthesize sensorMaxY3;
@synthesize signalMinX1;
@synthesize signalMaxX3;
@synthesize sensLabel;
@synthesize sigLabel;
//@synthesize buttonHelpSetUp;



-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    SignalViewController *passValue = [segue destinationViewController];
    ***passValue.sensorMin = [[sensorMinY1 text] floatValue];//sensorMinY1;***
    passValue.sensorMax = [[sensorMaxY3 text] floatValue];//sensorMaxY3;
    passValue.signalMin = [[signalMinX1 text] floatValue];//signalMinX1;
    passValue.signalMax = [[signalMaxX3 text] floatValue];//signalMaxX3;
    [passValue.labelSigUnits setText:sigLabel.text];
    [passValue.labelSensUnits setText:sensLabel.text];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [defaults setValue:signalMinX1.text forKey:@"X1"];
    [defaults setValue:signalMaxX3.text forKey:@"X3"];
    [defaults setValue:sensorMinY1.text forKey:@"Y1"];
    [defaults setValue:sensorMaxY3.text forKey:@"Y3"];

}
```

this is the code set up that works. I only added the table view controller then embedded it into a navigation controller. I then ctrl-drag from the help button(toolbar item) to the new navigation controller and created an automatic segue like i did before only this time i get the error, it is getting hung up on the line this is in the asterix above.

Comment: show what you did so far, add your code

Comment: Please add a more descriptive title! The current one says absolutely nothing about the nature of your problem.

Comment: Sorry, first post forgot to edit title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prepareForSegue` is called for every segue going out of your view controller. If you have multiple segues, you have to give them all identifiers, then check the identifier in `prepareForSegue` and perform the right actions there.

At the moment you're assuming that the destination controller for *any* segue is a SignalViewController.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I'll try that approach in the morning. Thank you.